# MPI send and receive struct of structs

Tags: c++, c, mpi

how can i send and receive this type of structs via MPI?

```
struct controlPoint{
    int hour,minute,second,x,y,z;
};

struct flight{
    int flightNum, controlNum;
    vector<controlPoint> point;
};

vector<flight> flights;
```

a sample code will be very helpful

Comment: Related: [struct serialization in C and transfer over MPI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864510/struct-serialization-in-c-and-transfer-over-mpi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to invoke the magic of [user-defined datatypes](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node72.html#SECTION00420000000000000000). First, define an [MPI_Contiguous](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node74.html#SECTION00431000000000000000) datatype for `controlPoint`: let's call it `cp_type`. Next, you'll need an [MPI_Struct](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node79.html#SECTION00436000000000000000) to represent `flight`, which we'll call `flight_type`. This is a bit tricky, since you can't pass a `vector` through MPI (without outside help from e.g. Bost). Fortunately, you don't really need to: `vector` guarantees contiguous storage, just like an array. So your MPI_Struct would consist of 2 blocks: the first block has two integers with an offset of 0 (`flightNum` and `controlNum`), and the second block has `point.size()` number of `cp_type`s, with an offset of `point[0]`. This way, you only send the data from the `vector`, and none of its implementation details. After this, you can send your struct as a single element of `flight_type`.

Receiving is almost trivial: just define the same MPI datatypes as above, and receive your data as a single copy of this type. Note however, that the `flight` struct that you receive into will need to have enough space in its `point` vector to receive all the content. You can just `resize()` it before defining the MPI datatypes: that way, enough space will be allocated, and the values will be overwritten during the receive.

Comment: `MPI_datatype = cp_type, flight_type;
 MPI_Type_contiguous(6, MPI_INT, &cp_type);
 MPI_Type_struct(2, {2,3} , MPI_Aint *array_of_displacements, {MPI_INT,cp_type}, &flight_type);
 MPI_Send(flights, flights.size(), flight_type, n, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` @suszterpatt i think i got it but i don't know what exectly to write in the "array of displacements".

Comment: `int a[2] = {2,3};
 MPI_Aint b[2] = {0,2*sizeof(int)};
 MPI_Datatype cp_type, flight_type;
 MPI_Type_contiguous(6, MPI_INT, &cp_type);
 MPI_Datatype c[2] = {MPI_INT,cp_type};
 MPI_Type_struct(2, a, b, c, &flight_type);
 MPI_Send(&flights, 1, flight_type, n, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` @suszterpatt this is my code i get a fatal error "invalid datatype", "error stack", "datatype has not been committed"

Comment: @Ben: Two things. First, use `MPI_Address()` to find the address of `point[0]`, and use that as the second element of your displacement vector. That's where the actual data is. 2 `int`s after the beginning of the struct is where the start of the `vector` object is, but the data is likely kept someplace else in memory. Second: you have to commit MPI datatypes with `MPI_Commit()` after defining them. You're getting that error because you're trying to define the struct using the uncommitted contiguous datatype.

Comment: @suszterpatt i have a vector of the structs "flight" so it means that i have to find the address for each one of the varibles in the vector. but then i can't define the struct because the address is different each time. i tried to send only one element of the struct and i used MPI_Commit & MPI_Address i also made an empty struct of "flight" in the reciever to be overwritten, but its still not working. maybe there is a simple way to do it with MPI_Pack?

Comment: @Ben: you can redefine (and recommit) the datatype with different displacements and send the structs one by one. Or, though I wouldn't recommend it, define a separate datatype for each element, and then another Struct for the whole vector of `flight`s. You can try MPI_Pack, but keep in mind that it always creates a copy of your data, which can be costly.