# Automatically generate struct instances

Tags: c, struct

Lets say the struct is defined as :

```
struct car {
   int registration_number;
}
```

I want to generate a specific number of struct instances  as specified by the user.

```
Enter number of cars: 20
#generate 20 struct instances
```

I do not want to make an array inside struct but want a separate instance for every car. I cant understand what the protocol is to automatically generate instances.

```
car1,car2,car3......,car n
```

I thought I would run a loop but I cant understand how to declare new instance name everytime :

```
#some loop
struct car instance_name   #how to replace instance_name with actual names?
```

Comment: Make an array of structs. You can't create variable names at runtime.

Comment: @melpomene Clears a lot up. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly malloc for array of struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613752/how-to-properly-malloc-for-array-of-struct-in-c)

Comment: Make an array of struct if size n, choice is yours to declare it static or dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of structs. You can't create variable names at runtime. – melpomene

Answer (score -2):

If you don't know in advance how many car instances you will need, a handy solution is to use `malloc` to reserve more memory on the fly.

```
carArray = (struct car**) malloc(numberOfCars*sizeOf(struct car));

for (int i =0; i < numberOfCars; i++)
    carArray[i] = (struct car*) malloc (sizeof(struct car));
```

A helpful example article [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c31.htm)

A user with a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613752/how-to-properly-malloc-for-array-of-struct-in-c)

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`. And in this case either your cast or your `sizeof` expression is wrong. (Why use a 2-level structure anyway?)

Comment: Better: `struct car *cars; ... cars = malloc(num * sizeof *cars); ... cars[i].registration_number = 42;`