# How to automatically generate new instances of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, instance

I have a `vector` with a bunch of People `structs` inside of it. These People `structs` have information about the individual person. It's basically a huge tree. It would look like this if it were drawn out:

```
    Joe        Bob
    / \        / \
  Age Weight Age Weight
   |    |     |    |
  14   140   22   160
```

The people at the top are `structs`, and they are stored inside of a `vector<People>`. However, these people are generated while the program runs.

I can have the program generate the name (like "Bob"), but how can I create a new instance of the People `struct` that way?

This is similar to [Automatically generate struct instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964773/automatically-generate-struct-instances) but that doesn't have an answer that works.

Comment: With your previous question and this one, it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  IMHO a good reference book would answer most of your questions.

Comment: Are you aware of `new`?

Comment: Take a look at [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back). Nathan Oliver is right. C++ is an unforgiving language to learn without a good set of references. You can't even count on the Internet for most of it because until you have a good grasp of what good C++ looks like you can't filter out the bad information that makes up the vast majority of C++ tutorials and help sites.

Comment: It seems to be another homework assignment, learning to use dynamic memory, it seems.

Comment: That tree diagram isn’t very representative of the code. It makes it look like there are *strings* that ’own’ integers. That’s not how structs (in a vector) work. I’d forget the whole ’tree’ thing.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you defined `Person` as:

```
typedef struct {
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int weight;
} Person;
```

You can then create an instance like so:

```
Person p = {"Bob", 22, 70};
```

Comment: Let’s not suppose they use `typedef struct`.