# Why `push()` in my stack implementation isn't working correctly?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures

Zero errors and warnings, if I add `printf()` inside the `push()` function, it prints 5 and 7 as I want it to, but when I use it in `main()` I get 0 and 0.

```c
typedef struct Point {
    double x, y;
} Point;

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Point p[];
} Stack;

void push(Stack* stack, double value1, double value2)
{
    stack->size = stack->size++;
    stack->p[stack->size].x = value1;
    stack->p[stack->size].y = value2;
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack stack;
    Point p;
    stack.size = 0;
    stack.p[stack.size].x = 0;
    stack.p[stack.size].y = 0;
    push(&stack, 5, 7);
    printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
}
```

Comment: `Stack.p` is never initialized.

Comment: @fredrik how do I do that?

Comment: By assigning a value to it. Right now you're just declaring a pointer to an array of `Point` (or if you let the it degrade to its base form, just a pointer to a `Point`). So allocate memory for an array of Point and assign it to `Point.p`

Comment: Have a look at the `malloc()` function and its proper use.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613752/how-to-properly-malloc-for-array-of-struct-in-c) for a starting point.

Comment: @fredrik `p` is not a pointer, it's a flexible array member.

Answer (score 2):

> Zero errors and warnings

Use a better compiler, or learn how to use yours (unfortunately many compilers run in low-warning mode by default).

```
$ gcc -O -Wall -Wextra -Werror a.c
a.c: In function ‘push’:
a.c:12:17: error: operation on ‘stack->size’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
   12 |     stack->size = stack->size++;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:25:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   25 |     printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
      |     ^~~~~~
a.c:25:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [-Werror]
a.c:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
    1 | typedef struct Point {
a.c:25:14: error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Werror=format=]
   25 |     printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
      |             ~^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |       |
      |              double  double *
a.c:25:18: error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’ [-Werror=format=]
   25 |     printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
      |                 ~^                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |                           |
      |                  double                      double *
a.c:20:11: error: unused variable ‘p’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
   20 |     Point p;
      |           ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Let's see what the errors mean.

> ```
> a.c:12:17: error: operation on ‘stack->size’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
>    12 |     stack->size = stack->size++;
> ```

`stack->size++` means add one to `stack->size`, but if the value of this expression is used, it's the old value of `stack->size`. You use this expressions in an instruction that also assigns to `stack->size`. Generally speaking, when there are two assignments to the same variable or memory location (e.g. a structure field or an array element) in the same instruction, the behavior is undefined. “Undefined behavior” means that anything can happen. Some plausible behaviors include:

- This doesn't modify `stack->size` at all, because the compiler generated code for: 1. read old value; 2. store the result of `++`; 3. assign with `=`.
- This adds 1 to `stack->size`, because the compiler generated code for: 1. read old value; 2. assign with `=`; 3. store the result of `++`.
- This adds 2 to `stack->size`, because the compiler generated code for: 1. read old value for `++`; 2. store the result of `++`; 3. read old value for `=`; 4. store the result of `=`.

But other weirder behaviors are possible, including:

- Using different values for `stack->size` below, because the compiler has inconsistent knowledge about what the value of `stack->size` is after this instruction.
- The compiler deciding not to generate any code for the `push` function because since it's attempting to do something that's forbidden, the function must be called only in some particular case that can't happen with these particular build options.
- [Demons come out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) (if you have an adequate peripheral on your computer).

You obviously meant to add 1 to `stack->size`. So write either

```
++stack->size;
```

or

```
stack->size++;
```

or

```
stack->size += 1;
```

But only one of these. Don't mix them.

> ```
> a.c:25:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>    25 |     printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
>       |     ^~~~~~
> a.c:25:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [-Werror]
> a.c:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
>   +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
> ```

That one's easy: the compiler gives you the answer. Include `stdio.h`. The bit about “incompatible implicit declaration” is because since the declaration of `printf` was missing, the compiler guessed one, but it guessed wrong. The guessing rules date back from half a century ago and are not particularly useful, never rely on them.

> ```
> a.c:25:14: error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Werror=format=]
>    25 |     printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);
>       |             ~^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       |              |       |
>       |              double  double *
> ```

Here the compiler tells you what's wrong, and it should be easy to figure out what to do. To print a floating-point number, pass a floating-point value, not a pointer to one. So:

```
    printf("%f, %f", stack.p[stack.size].x, stack.p[stack.size].y);
```

> ```
> a.c:20:11: error: unused variable ‘p’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
> ```

That one means what it says. You declared a variable `p` but never use it. Just remove its declaration.

With the corrections above, your program might work, although there's one more problem that the compiler can't detect.

```
typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Point p[];
} Stack;
…
Stack stack;
```

This reserves zero entries in memory for `Stack.p`. It *might* work for you if your compiler decided to place the variable `Point p` immediately after `Stack stack` in memory, but that's heavily dependent on the compiler, on the presence of other variables, on the variable names, etc. You can't use a flexible array member like `Point p[]` in a local variable, only in memory allocated with `malloc` (in most cases). To keep things simple, start with a statically allocated size for the stack.

```
#define MAXIMUM_STACK_SIZE 42
typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Point p[MAXIMUM_STACK_SIZE];
} Stack;
```

Then your stack can grow up to that many elements.

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** initialize the flexible array member of your stack.

Change:

```
stack->size = stack->size++;
```

which invokes *Undefined Behavior*, to:

```
stack->size++;
```

Moreover, you need to remove the `&`s from `printf("%f, %f", &stack.p[stack.size].x, &stack.p[stack.size].y);`.

Putting everything together, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Point {
    double x, y;
} Point;

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Point p[];
} Stack;

void push(Stack* stack, double value1, double value2)
{
    stack->size++;
    stack->p[stack->size].x = value1;
    stack->p[stack->size].y = value2;
}

int main(void)
{
    // 1 for 1 Point
    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack) + sizeof(Point) * 1);
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->p[stack->size].x = 0;
    stack->p[stack->size].y = 0;
    push(stack, 5, 7);
    printf("%f, %f", stack->p[stack->size].x, stack->p[stack->size].y);
    
    free(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 5.000000, 7.000000

Read more in https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member

Comment: `Point p;` is never used, so there's no need to initialize it. Maybe you meant `Point p[];`, in which case it needs to be allocated as part of the containing struct, not by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a flexible array member?

If not, then you could declare your `Point` array struct data member as a pointer, and after taking care of incrementing size of stack and printing without references as I saw in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945882/2411320), then use [`malloc()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to dynamically allocate memory for your array (in this example I only allocate for 1 `Point`, but you can easily generalize it), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Point {
    double x, y;
} Point;

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Point* p;
} Stack;

void push(Stack* stack, double value1, double value2)
{
    stack->size++;
    stack->p[stack->size].x = value1;
    stack->p[stack->size].y = value2;
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack stack;
    // 1 for 1 Point
    stack.p = malloc(1 * sizeof(Point));
    stack.size = 0;
    stack.p[stack.size].x = 0;
    stack.p[stack.size].y = 0;
    push(&stack, 5, 7);
    printf("%f, %f", stack.p[stack.size].x, stack.p[stack.size].y);

    free(stack.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 5.000000, 7.000000