# segmentation fault for array of struct in c OPEN-MPI

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmpi

I've created a structure like this:

```
typedef struct point_struct { int x, y; }point;
```

And in  main i defined it like this:

```
int num_item =2;
int blocklengths[2] = {1,1};
MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
MPI_Datatype mpi_point_type;
MPI_Aint offsets[2];
offsets[0] = offsetof(point, x);
offsets[1] = offsetof(point, y);
MPI_Type_create_struct(num_item, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_point_type );
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_point_type);
```

I've `scatter`ed it between processes and call a recursive function to do something.
Mpirun throws back this error:

> Process received signal.
>       Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
>       Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
>       Failing at address: 0x7fffb9be57dc
>       mpirun noticed that process rank 3 with PID 2924 on 
>       node MY_COMPUTER exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

I also `malloc` my array of structure this way:

```
 point *p_x = (struct point_struct*)malloc(n*sizeof(struct point_struct));
```

Do i `malloc`ed it wrong? or whats the problem?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you read [about cast of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)?

Comment: what should i know? whats wring with my code?

Comment: You don't want to cast malloc since it is a void * and can easily be assigned to any pointer. Read the link above more information about that. But that shouldn't be the error in your code, it's just good practice.

Comment: Thanks for practice suggestion but i should submit my project before tomorrow night. I'll do that another time @yashwanth

Comment: @francis really i used this question for my structure definition : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864510/struct-serialization-in-c-and-transfer-over-mpi
i dont know what is this function implementation

Comment: Sorry : `offsetof()` is part of stddef and I cannot see any problem in the code you posted. Could you post the code related to the `mpi_scatter()` ? Did you allocate memory for the receive buffer on all processes ? The error can also be created by a wrong `sendcount` or a wrong `recvcount`... More code is needed to answer your question !

Comment: @francis:  actually i've found what was my problem. but im blocked and i cant post answer to it. what should i do? i changed my `malloc` code and it worked. here is my new `malloc` : `struct point_struct *p_x = (struct point_struct*)malloc(n*sizeof(struct point_struct));` you may post it as an answer, i'll accept it. thank you for your time.