# C++ MPI create and send array of structs which has fields char[16] and integer

Tags: c++, struct, mpi, mpich

I know there is a question on the site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871068/create-and-communicate-an-array-of-structs-using-mpi-derived-datatypes) about this but that is implemented in c. I need c++ version of it.

Problem is the following:
I created a struct which has the following form

```
struct word
{
   char value[WORD_MAX_LENGTH];
   int freq;
};
```

I need to send the array of these structs. How can I serialize this struct and send say 500 of them to another process using MPI_Send.

Here is where I got so far:

```
    MPI_Datatype word_type, oldtypes[2];
    int blockcounts[2];
    MPI_Aint offsets[2], extent;

    //Determine the offset and block length of the first element of the struct which is a char array.
    offsets[0] = 0;
    oldtypes[0] = MPI_CHAR;
    blockcounts[0] = WORD_MAX_LENGTH;

    //Determine the offset of int ferq of the struct.
    MPI_Type_extent(MPI_CHAR, &extent);
    offsets[1] = 16 * extent;
    blockcounts[1] = 1;

    // Finally create the type.
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &word_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&word_type);
```

When I do this, it compiles with no error however when I try to run it.
It complains

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Type_create_struct: Invalid datatype, error stack:

PMPI_Type_create_struct(173): MPI_Type_create_struct(count=2, 
array_of_blocklengths=0x7fffbd059f70,   
array_of_displacements=0x7fffbd059f80, array_of_types=0x7fffbd059f60, 
newtype=0x7fffbd059f14) failed

PMPI_Type_create_struct(142): Invalid datatype
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Note: I can't use boost libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues

- `oldtypes[1]` is not initialized
- `offsets[1]` looks odd, you can use the `offsetsof()` macro instead

You might also have to `MPI_Type_create_resized()` if your compiler adds some padding at the end of the `word` strict.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have forgotten editing offsets after asking the question. I have already changed it thanks for heads up anyway.They look like this offsets[1] = (size_t)&(word.freq) - (size_t)&word; now. Also I added the MPI_INT to oldtypes. It seems working now thank you :D

Comment: This is working. How can I send multiple of these structs to slaves ?

Comment: `MPI_Send(words, n, word_type, ...)`