# How to transmit vectors of different types in MPI using one broadcast

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, mpi

I have some vectors that I want to transmit between processes using MPI in C++. I have been using `broadcast` to exchange the data one vector at a time, but it doesn't seem to scale up well with the number of processes. I was told that this is because I am using too many broadcast calls and it causes too much lag as the number of processes increases. Therefore, it was recommended to me to pack all the data in one structure, and send them all in one go.

My problem is that my vectors are of type `int` and `double` (2 vectors of each type), and their length is not known at compile time (it's equal to the number of processes). Therefore, I cannot create a `struct` to hold all the data and then broadcast that using a custom MPI structure (MPI_Type_create_struct) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864510/struct-serialization-in-c-and-transfer-over-mpi) because it requires to hardcode the sizes of the c-arrays at compile time. I know how to create the MPI custom structure, but I can't figure out how to pack the data into a struct in order to send it.

So, to sum up, is there a way to broadcast 4 vectors of different types (2 int and 2 double) between processes using only one broadcast?

Comment: MPI structured datatypes are generic and don't really need to correspond to C/C++ `struct`s.

Comment: That's true, but then how can I use that to actually send the data? As an example, I could use : MPI_Send(&custom_object_to_send,   1, mpi_custom_type, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD); but I need to create custom_object_to_send and assign values to it so that I can send it, and, as far as I can tell, this needs to be buildable in the language.

Comment: No, you don't. You simply create an MPI structure type and specify the absolute address of the beginning of each array/vector as the offset, then specify `MPI_BOTTOM` as the data buffer address in the call to `MPI_Send`. Just use your favourite search engine to search for `"MPI_Type_create_struct" "MPI_BOTTOM"`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Numbers such as "4.1.2" refer to chapters in the MPI standard v3.0*

This should be possible with `MPI_Type_create_struct` (4.1.2) and without an actual C-`struct`.

Use `MPI_Type_vector` (4.1.2) to create two data types. One for a vector of `int` and one for a vector of `double` as you'll get from `vector<>::data()`. You can assume, that `vector<>` stores the data in a continuous way.
You can feed `MPI_Type_vector` with the size values at runtime.

Now use `MPI_Type_create_struct` to combine two instances of each of the two vector types into a single datatype, which you then can easily use for communication.

With `MPI_Get_address` (4.1.5) we can get the MPI-friendly address of a variable at runtime. You'll probably need that during construction of the derived datatype for the virtual struct. (Read the advices to the user in the MPI standard on why *not* using `&`)

For more flexibility, omit the intermediate vector data types and directly compute the addresses and extends of the `vector<>::data()` arrays and feed that directly into `MPI_Type_create_struct`.

---

*Disclaimer: IIRC, I've been using this approach successfully for sending multiple non-continuous blocks of continuous data with single messages (some time ago).*